# Apache wont start after Ubuntu 12 to 14 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, apache2

On our VM system, I did an upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04.. for the most part, the upgrade seemed to run fine, usually accepting the default prompts along the way. There was one issue which kept coming back with errors, and it had to do with the phpmyadmin database stuff. Been so long since I ran that, I couldn't remember the passwords for that login, so eventually it was aborted/cancelled. The package upgrade ended, but said there were some errors. Didn't say exactly what but.. I did a reboot of the server, and for the most part our stuff seems to be there, at least what is showing in the WebMin side. (Sorry for webmin stuff, but.. my linux command line prompt work leaves a lot to be desired.. Anyway...)

The Apache webmin module correctly shows the additional web servers. But when I go to start Apache it comes back with:

Failed to start apache :

- Starting web server apache2
- - The apache2 configtest failed.
    Output of config test was:
    apache2: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
    Action 'configtest' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information.

I did a search, there was a mention of changing the etc/apache2.conf file for this:

replaced LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
with Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

Saved the file after putting that edit in, tried to restart Apache again, and got the same error. Line 214 says "Include httpd.conf" and of course that file does not exist in the apache2 folder, or any of the other folders in there.

Not quite sure what to do at this point...

Gary :)

---

Well ok, this is getting very strange. Today I tried to login to the server (which is still running 'fine'... coughs) with both WinSCP and Filezilla, and could not connect. No error messages, just would not connect.

Tried running putty through WinSCP, and could not connect. My home IP has not changed, it is the only IP "allowed" in hosts.allow... There are no records of errors or connects from my home system to the server in the var/log/auth.log file...

None of this makes sense because yesterday after doing the update from 12 to 14, I had rebooted the server from the hosting companies control panel, and I had connected into the system using the WinSCP side, and connected in via putty using the WinSCP side. Putty even told me that we were running 14, and even showed the "upgrade to 16 with do-relese-update" (which of course, I did not do).

Thankfully WebMin is still running and active, so I can use that to edit whatever may be broken... I just don't know why I can't connect in now, when I could yesterday (after doing the update)..

Any ideas? This is turning into quite the disaster...

Comment: Hmmm.. out of curiosity, I changed the "Include httpd.conf" entry to "Include conf.d" .. saved the changes.. started Apache, and it seems to work. The default site opens, the other 2 websites open.. Not sure if this 'fix' was the correct way to do things but, for the moment... it is at least working :)

Comment: New information should go in as edits and NOT as new answers to your question. I've cloned your more-information not-an-answer answer into your post as an edit and removed the non-answer post.

Comment: sorry Thomas, new to the system, not familiar with the rules... just getting into a panic mode with not being able to SSH in...